# Getting a modified text from an input in an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date, text-formatting

I need to make a booking form for a hotel website. It needs to get some basic information and send it to my booking engine.

My problem is that my booking engine needs to receive any date as a mm/dd/yyyy formatted text. Unfortunately, most European users are not used to that format, as they use dd/mm/yyyy.

So, I need the user to write and see their input information in dd/mm/yyyy, but the booking engine should receive it as mm/dd/yyyy.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<form action="..." onsubmit="return ChangeDate()" id="resform" name="resform" target="_blank" method="get">

<input type="text" name="DateIn">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function ChangeDate() {
    var x = document.forms["resform"["DateIn"].value.split('/');
    return document.forms["resform"]["DateIn"].innerHTML = x[1]+'/'+x[0]+'/'+x[2];
    }
</script>
```

I keep getting the format dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Can you not use a `date` input element rather than text?

Comment: What does the `yyyyyy` yield in terms of a valid year???

Comment: That was a mistake! It's `yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

It's preferable to use:

```html
<input type="date" id="dateIn"/>
```

In text field the user can input anything he wants unless you created a JS function to prevent him.

Moreover, The format in chrome,edge,safari... of date input in the browser is mm/dd/yyyy, Whereas in Firefox browser it is dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use the `date` type input field and then use the [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) class to format your output you should be able to display as one thing and send the value as another. I was a little confused by the `yyyyyy` in the question and which format is expected by the booking engine but hope this will provide insight into how you might accomplish the goals.

```js
const oForm=document.forms.resform;
const oDate=oForm.DateIn;
const oBttn=oForm.querySelector('[type="submit"]');


oBttn.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  if( oDate.value!='' ){
    const date=new Date( oDate.value );
    const opts={ year:'numeric', month:'2-digit', day:'2-digit' };
    const formatted=new Intl.DateTimeFormat( 'en-US', opts ).format( date );
    
    console.info( 'Formatted date value: %s',formatted ) 
 }
});
```

```html
<form name='resform' target='_blank' method='get'>
    <input type='date' name='DateIn' />
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: So far I can't get that javascript to work, but I think I'll get it thanks to you, I am grateful!

Comment: When you say you can't get it to work how do you mean? Is the output format incorrect or are you hoping to change the format?

Comment: The booking engine now gets yyyy-mm-dd, which I guess means the javascript is not connecting correctly with my HTML. I have tried including it as a script, and also in a js template, to no avail. I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong... I barely know javascript, but your code runs perfectly here in your comment.